# Scroll sections using tailwindcss

Tags: html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

so i have a code that look like this

```
<div className='w-[50%] h-full flex items-center justify-center flex-col'>
        <div className='container grid grid-cols-2 grid-rows-4 p-10 gap-5 w-full h-full'>
            <div className='row-span-1 border-2 border-black'>1</div>
            <div className='row-span-2 border-2 border-black'>2</div>
            <div className='row-span-2 border-2 border-black'>3</div>
            <div className='row-span-2 border-2 border-black'>4</div>
            <div className='row-span-1 border-2 border-black'>5</div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Resulting to a layout that looks like this

[image]

If i added another one of this section below my code the result is this

[image]

How to make those 2 section not merge height with one another and the user can scroll instead??

Comment: I tried using flex shrink-0 but the top container clipped instead

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot of the expected result... also please do all of this in code sandbox so we can edit :)

Comment: I didn't see any issue here while reproducing it. Can you present any live demo here mentioning the same issue.

Comment: Can you accept my answer as I've also given the same solution as you mentioned...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer is pretty simple, I added `<section>` tags outside of each grids

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand you need to duplicate the section in the first pic below the already present section... this is one way to achieve it.

```
<section className="h-full overflow-y-scroll">
                <div className='w-[50%] h-full flex items-center justify-center flex-col'>
                    <div className='container grid grid-cols-2 grid-rows-4 p-10 gap-5 w-full h-full'>
                        <div className='row-span-1 border-2 border-black'>1</div>
                        <div className='row-span-2 border-2 border-black'>2</div>
                        <div className='row-span-2 border-2 border-black'>3</div>
                        <div className='row-span-2 border-2 border-black'>4</div>
                        <div className='row-span-1 border-2 border-black'>5</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className='w-[50%] h-full flex items-center justify-center flex-col'>
                    <div className='container grid grid-cols-2 grid-rows-4 p-10 gap-5 w-full h-full'>
                        <div className='row-span-1 border-2 border-black'>1</div>
                        <div className='row-span-2 border-2 border-black'>2</div>
                        <div className='row-span-2 border-2 border-black'>3</div>
                        <div className='row-span-2 border-2 border-black'>4</div>
                        <div className='row-span-1 border-2 border-black'>5</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
```

and this is the output with scrollbar
[image]
[image]